# Unresolved package 'flutter' , android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" and others

Tags: flutter

When I created a flutter application, I met the problem which in the fllowing pictures.Did I miss some configurations or files?

[my AndroidMainifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzZ54.png)

[my code analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7azo4.png)

There is my build.gradle file in app factory.

[bulid.gradle1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcslE.png)

[build.gradle2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8M5x.png)

And this is my another build.gradle file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr45Q.png)

[Another AndroidMainifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoJa.png)

Comment: Please post the contents of your build.gradle files.

Comment: @CEO tech4lifeapps
I've upgrated,sir.

Comment: You've shown only a portion of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. The `<manifest...` root element should have a `package` attribute. What value is in this attribute?

Comment: It's com.example.First.I've added the picture of that.